# Ajaxtabcontrol is not showing in web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using Ajax tabcontrol ...Here is my code

```
<table id="tblajaxtab">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatetabcontrol" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <cc1:TabContainer ID="tabcontainer" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" AutoPostBack="false"
                        OnDemand="true" ScrollBars="None" UseVerticalStripPlacement="true" Height="250px"
                        Width="500px"   VerticalStripWidth="120px" TabStripPlacement="Top">
                        <cc1:TabPanel ID="SQlServer" runat="server" HeaderText="SQL Server" Enabled="true"
                            OnDemandMode="Once" ScrollBars="Auto">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <table id="tblsqlserver">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Database table name
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txttablename" runat="server" Width="180"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </cc1:TabPanel>
                        <cc1:TabPanel ID="csv" runat="server" Enabled="true" OnDemandMode="Once" HeaderText="CSV">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </cc1:TabPanel>
                    </cc1:TabContainer>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

when I run this. Nothing is displaying. Please can you tell we whats wrong with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a ToolkitScriptManager  in your code.

Please refer this link below.

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/11/ajax-tabcontainer-sample-or-how-to.html

Hope it help.

Comment: Sorry upvote requires 15 reputation i don,t have ..when i have it i will definitely vote u

Comment: Ok, No problem. Please remember to vote my answer, when your reputation is increase than 15  Please carry on your coding...